# Proving that $\tau_*$ is coarser than $\tau_n$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X$ denote a normed vector space and $X^{*}$ the corresponding dual space (Linear, continuous functionals  $\ell : X \rightarrow \Phi$ equipped with the usual operator norm).

Consider the norm-topology $\tau_n$ on $X^{*}$

$$
\tau_n = \{ U \subseteq X^{*} \colon \forall \ell \in X^{*} \ \exists \delta>0 : \{\ell ' \in X^* \colon \Vert \ell' - \ell \Vert < \delta  \} \subseteq U \},
$$

as well as the weak*-topology $\tau_*$ on $X^{*}$

$$
\tau_* = \{ \text{ev}_x^{-1}(U) \colon x \in X, U \text{ open in } \Phi\}.
$$

where $\text{ev}_{x}: \ell \mapsto \ell(x)$.

**I want to prove that $\tau_*$ is smaller (coarser) than $\tau_n$.**

For this it suffices to show that a basis for $\tau_{*}$ is contained in a basis of $\tau_n$. A subbasis for $\tau_*$ (as a special case of the product topology) consists of the following elements:
$$
\mathcal{U}_{\delta, A}(\ell) = \{ \ell' \in X^* \colon \Vert \text{ev}_x(\ell') - \text{ev}_x(\ell) \Vert < \delta \ \forall x \in A \} =  \{ \ell' \in X^* \colon \sup_{x \in A} \Vert \ell'(x) - \ell(x) \Vert < \delta \} 
$$
where $\delta > 0$ and $A$ is a finite, non-empty set. A basis for $\tau_n$ consists of the following elements:
$$
B(\ell, \delta) = \{ \ell' \in X^* \colon \sup_{\Vert x \Vert \leq 1} \Vert \ell'(x) - \ell(x) \Vert < \delta \}  
$$
where again $\delta > 0$. These conditions seem very similar which leads to believe I am on the right track. Taking any $\mathcal{U}_{\delta, A}(\ell)$ we know want to show this is just a union of the above "norm" balls $B(\ell, \delta)$.

However I am stuck here so if anyone could help me advance this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The weak* topology on $X^\ast$ is practically by definition the smallest (=coarsest) topology on $X^\ast$ which makes all evaluations $\mathrm{ev}_x$ continuous; these maps are continuous with respect to the norm topology, so the norm topology must be finer than the weak*.

Comment: By the way, what is $\Phi$? It should be the ground field, i.e., usually the reals or the complex numbers.

Comment: @arnett Must be yes, I've seen $\Bbb K$ (Körper) used for the underlying field if we want something for both complex and real numbers. $\Phi$ seems weird, must be a text book specific thing.

Comment: @arnett Yes $\Phi$ is exactly the complex or the reals. Why are the evaluations continuous w.r.t. the norm topology?

Comment: The definition of $\tau^\ast$ is wrong ; it merely gives the subbase for it (enough for a definition, granted, but $\tau^\ast$ is larger than that.

Comment: I have changed it to subbasis now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every $\text{ev}_x: (X^\ast, \tau_n) \to \Phi$ is continuous, as for every $\ell \in X^\ast$ we have $|\text{ev}_x(\ell)| = |\ell(x)| \le \|\ell\|\|x\|$, so $\text{ev}_x$ is Lipschitz etc.

By definition $\tau^\ast$ is the **minimal** topology on $X^\ast$ that makes all $\text{ev}_x, x \in X$ continuous, while $\tau_n$ is *one* such topology, as we saw. It follows that $\tau^\ast \subseteq \tau_n$ and you're done.

You don't need to go into  the basic subsets of $\tau^\ast$, that's TMI.
If you insist on it show that

$$B(\ell, \delta) \subseteq \mathcal{U}_{\delta, A}(\ell)$$

for any $\delta>0$, $A \subseteq X$ (tou can take them all in the unit ball of $X$, in fact) and $\ell \in X^\ast$, which implies that all $\tau^\ast$-interior points of a set will also be $\tau_n$-interior points of that set. A moment's thought will then reveal that this is sufficient for the claim. But this feels like too much "work". The previous argument by minimality is the crux and essence, IMO.

Comment: The minimality argument is clever, I can see that. However where exactly do you actually use the particular operator norm topology? It seems this would work for any norm topology on $X^*$. But maybe that is the point? That every norm topology will be finer that the weak* topology since evaluations are Lipschitz in all of those.

Comment: Ah I just realised you us the operator norm for the inequality. So maybe not all norm topologies are Lipschitz anyway :)

Comment: @Jacobiman the definition of the operator norm ( as a sup of values) makes the evaluations continuous and then it works. But I think any “reasonable “ topology on $X^\ast$ will make the evaluations continuous.